# SQL matching with rest of the columns if any of the where condition parameter is missing

Tags: sql

Here is my table structure:

```
ID cid Name Course  Interval

1   1  KB    Y        2
2   1  TB    Y        3
3   2  BK    N        1
```

I need to write a query which returns all rows with matching  condition.
if at all any of the parameter is null or not provided then i need to return all of the matching rows.

In my select query if my parameters are (cid ==1 and Name== null and course ==Y  or (cid ==1  and course ==Y ) then I need to return rows with id
1 and 2.
What exactly I need is this:
If I get all the matching record then i can take interval corresponding to the record. Else I need to take average interval of the matching record

Comment: What SQL have you already tried? Will this be dynamically built in a proc or will it be built in the program? Or be done with Case/If/etc? Could build whole WHERE?

Comment: It is possible with dynamically built query. I wonder if there is any other approach rather than using dynamic query to implement it using proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after? Its a variable number or arguments - in my case the parameters are explicitly defined, yours may be passed in from a stored proc etc.

```
-- Create the table
create table #t(ID int, cid int, Name char(2), Course char(1),  Interval int)
insert #t values (1,1,'KB','Y',2)
,(2,1,'TB','Y',3)
,(3,2,'BK','N',1)

-- Declare the arguments
declare @cid int
declare @name char(2)
declare @course char(1)

-- Set one or more arguments
set @cid=1
set @name=null
set @course='Y'

select AVG(convert(decimal(5,2),interval)) from #t 
where isnull(@cid,cid)=cid 
and isnull(@name,name)=name
and isnull(@course,course)=course
```